# Can't delete a folder using File::deleteDirectory

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a function that deletes an album, all images that belong to that album, the thumbnails folder and lastly the folder with album name.

So these are the paths to the folders I want to delete:

```
C:\MAMP\htdocs\LaravelProject\public\storage\uploads\albums\test
C:\MAMP\htdocs\LaravelProject\public\storage\uploads\albums\test\thumbnails
```

Both test and thumbnails are folders. What I've tried so far is:

```
public function deleteAlbum($albumId){

        $album = Album::where('id', $albumId)->first();
        $albumImages = AlbumImage::where('album_id', $albumId)->get();
        $album->tags()->detach();
        $album->delete();

        foreach ($albumImages as $albumImage) {
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/albums/'.$album->name.'/'.$albumImage->file_name);
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/albums/'.$album->name.'/thumbnails/'.$albumImage->file_name);
        }

        File::deleteDirectory('public/storage/uploads/albums/'.$album->name.'/thumbnails');
        File::deleteDirectory('public/storage/uploads/albums/'.$album->name);

        return redirect()->route('home');

    }
```

However, this code deletes the images but leaves the folder without deleting them and I've no idea why.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Tag;
use App\Album;
use App\AlbumImage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Image as InterventionImage;
use App\Image;
```

Comment: Try to set correct permissions. Set chmod 777 for debug on folder you which you are trying to remove

Comment: When I'm creating a the folder, I use File::makeDirectory(public_path($path), 0777, true, true); . That does the same thing, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the directory too. you have to pass the second parameter as a false.

```
    File::deleteDirectory('public/storage/uploads/albums/'.$album->name.'/thumbnails', false);
    File::deleteDirectory('public/storage/uploads/albums/'.$album->name, false);
```

if you want to delete the directory then you have to pass the `false` other wise the directory will be presevered and not deleted.

```
File::deleteDirectory('path/to/folder', false)
```

Here is the underlying function so you can have a clear idea.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still can't delete it even after adding these changes. I'm starting to wonder if my path is wrong.

Comment: @Bobimaru please post the namespaces that you are importing

Comment: Added it at bottom of post.

Comment: @Bobimaru please try passing the false as a second parameter

Comment: @Bobimaru are you using linux or windows?

Comment: I'm using Windows. Also still can't delete them after passing false as the second param. ;(

Comment: ```@rmdir($directory);``` I  think it is not working in windows maybe.